# How to draw a vertex with square root and fraction in it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I'm trying to draw a vertex of (sqrt(3)/2, 1) in tikz latex. I know how to do a point with square root, but I don't know how to add the fraction to it.

My code is

```
\draw (0,0)--({(sqrt(3)}/2,1);
```

But it kept giving me an error message. However, the code

```
\draw (0,0)--({(sqrt(3)},1);
```

is fine, but it's not what I want. There must be a way to do it, I just don't know how. Please help!

Comment: The 2 has to be inside of the brackets too. `\draw (0,0)--({(sqrt(3))/2},1);`

Comment: `\draw (0,0)--({((sqrt(3)/2)},1);`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole computation should be inside a pair of brackets. So, type

```
\draw (0,0)--({(sqrt(3)/2},1);
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0)--({(sqrt(3)},1);
    \draw (0,0)--({((sqrt(3)/2)},1);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```